# Giving a direction to a moving object

Tags: math, sdl

I wish to create a tower defense game in SDL. Before starting the project, I experiment everything I will need to do when programming the game. In the test I am doing currently, there are a tower (static object), targets (moving objects) that are in its range, and shoots (moving objects) that are fired from the turret to the targets. **What I fail to do is find a way to give the 'shoot' objects a direction**. By shoot object, I mean the object that is fired by the tower when targets are in range. Also, whatever the direction is, the shoot shall always have the same speed, which forbids the use of the formula `dirx = x2 - x1`.

Shoots are structures defined as the following:

```
typedef struct shoot
{
    SDL_Surface *img; // Visual representation of the shoot object.
    SDL_Rect pos;     // Position of the object, it's a structure containing
                      // coordinates x and y (these are of type int).
    int index;
    float dirx;       // dirx and diry are the movement done by the shoots object in
                      // 1 frame, so that for each frame, the object shoot is moved dirx
                      // pixels on the axis x and diry pixels on the axis y
    float diry;       // (the program deals with the fact that the movement will be done
                      // with integers and not with floats, that is no problem to me)
    float posx;       // posx and posy are the real, precise coordinates of the shoot
    float posy;
    struct shoot *prev;
    struct shoot *next;
} shoot;
```

What I need is a way to calculate the position of the object shoot in the next frame, given its position and direction in the current frame.

This is the best I could find (please note that it is a paper written formula, so the names are simplified, different from the names in the code):

- `dirx = d * ((p2x - p1x) / ((p2x - p1x) + (p2y - p1y)))`
- `diry = d * ((p2y - p1y) / ((p2x - p1x) + (p2y - p1y)))`

  1. `dirx` and `diry` correspond to the movement done, in the pixel, by the shoot on the axis x and y, in one frame.
  2. `d` is a multiplier and the big parenthesis (all of what is not `d`) is a coefficient.
  3. `p2` is the point the shoot shall aim for (the center of the target aimed for). `p1` is the current position of the shoot object. `x` or `y` means that we use the coordinate x or y of the point.

The problem with this formula is that it gives me an unexact value. For example, aiming in diagonal will make the shoot slower that aiming straight north. Moreover, it doesn't go in the right direction, and I can't find why since my paper tests show me I'm right...

I would love some help here to find a formula that makes the shoot move correctly.

Comment: Any chance that, in "((p2x - p1x) + (p2y - p1y))" each result of subtraction should be squared before addition, then the sum square rooted?

Comment: @ThomasJager I just tested this with my formula and the results are still wrong (testing with a direction in diagonal South West and an expected movement of 2 pixels, got -0.125 whereas I should have something like -1.6 or -1.7).

Comment: Can you give an example with the specific number input?

Comment: p1 = (4;4) and p2 = (2;2)

Comment: `dirx` would be: 0.5 and `diry` too aren't they? I don't think that this is what you want. Your formulas seems to be wrong. I don't see why the formulas are: `dirx = Δx / (Δx + Δy)` and `diry = Δy / (Δx + Δy)`

Comment: yes that is what I am saying: my formula is wrong. `dirx` and `diry` should not be 0.5.

Comment: Based on p1 = (4;4) and p2 = (2;2), I'm getting that ((p2x - p1x) / sqrt((p2x - p1x)^2 + (p2y - p1y)^2)) and it's y equivalent should each have a magnitude of ~0.7. This is still wrong, and I'm not sure what your equation is calculating as it is, but I'm fairly sure you must have those squares and square root. Also, note that in what I wrote above, ^2 means square, not XOR.

Comment: Please show your paper tests and explain your reasoning that they show your formula is right. Do you use the results differently between your paper test and your program?

Comment: Ìn my opinion `dirx` should be just `Δx = px2 - px1` and `diry` should be `Δy = py2 - py1` multiplicated with a scaling factor.

Comment: Define the result you want, e.g. "direction is a 2D vector of length 1.0, which  points from tower to position of the moving target at the time the tower aimed", or "direction is the difference of two positions of the fyling object, between Tn and Tn+1 (e.g. T1 and T2)".

Comment: @AndreKampling this formula would make distances in the diagonal higher than distances to the left, right, up, or down, whereas I want them to be equal.

Comment: @nounoursnoir: Which is right, a diagonal with same Δx like a horizontal is longer. If you want something different be accurate about what you're expecting. I have to say that I didn't get what you're expecting/what you need. Make a full calculation example paste it well formatted into your question.

Comment: @AndreKampling true, I will modify my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `p1` is the source of a `shoot` object, `p2` is the destination, and `s` is the speed you want to move it at (units per frame or per second - latter is better), then the *velocity* of the object is given by

```
float dx = p2.x - p1.x, dy = p2.y - p1.y,
      inv = s / sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
velx = inv * dx; vely = inv * dy;
```

(You should probably change `dir` to `vel` as it is a more sensible variable name)

---

Your attempt seems to be normalizing the direction vector by *Manhattan distance*, which is wrong - you must normalize by the *Euclidean distance*, which is given by the `sqrt` term.